Transistor AND gate problem
I am new to electronics and I built a simple AND gate from 2N2222 transistors. I want to use the output from the AND gate in a different circuits not just an LED but maby an OR gate. Can someone tell me how? [

Hi and welcome. Try to ask the question with details. At the moment, it's not clear what the question actually is. Try adding the schematic of the circuits. What the "different" circuit?

Welcome! Click on edit and then on the schematic symbol. From there you can draw what you have built.

What you created is an NAND with an open collector output. The Output would be at the collector of the upper transistor and the LED will light up when the output is low.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
By adding a totem pole output stage we've basically created a very simple TTL logic AND with push pull characteristics.
One issue with this circuit is that the two inputs do not behave the same and even change behaviour depending on the other input. That's why integrated circuits use dual gate transistors and funcy stuff like that. But as a proof of concept this could work.

This is an RTL AND, not TTL.
